# R Closures cannot access variables within closures

Tags: r, closures

I am moving from plain R code to R functions. In order to use R closure I have wrapped in 2 functions (authentication and download), whereof (download) has a dependency of needing input from authentication.

My understanding is that if I create a closure the variables inside the closure should be accessible for the entire inside of closure. If that is the case howcome function [downloadData] cannot fetch the variables from [authenticationKeys] ?

Currently I am solving the problem by having (authenticate) and (download) in separate R files and sourcing them into a main.R. Problem is though that I then get the result of the variables into global scope which seems to be not recommended. Furthen on, by sourcing the files I cannot utilize the function arguments and I cannot utilize the functional programming benefits by calling only parts of code when needed.

```
runAll <- function() {

    # Authentication
    authenticate <- function() {
      auhtenticationKeys <- list (
        "key1" = 1,
        "key2" = 2,
        "key3" = 3
      )
    }

    authenticate()

    # Download 
    downloadData <- function() {

      # Access authentication keys:
      auhtenticationKeys$key1
      auhtenticationKeys$key2
      auhtenticationKeys$key3

      myData <- list (
        "open"  = 10,
        "high"  = 11,
        "low"   = 12,
        "close" = 13
      )
    }

    downloadData()

}

runAll()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always assign variables you are interested in to other environments outside the closure you are working on:

```
runAll <- function() {

  # Authentication
  authenticate <- function() {
    auhtenticationKeys <- list (
      "key1" = 1,
      "key2" = 2,
      "key3" = 3
    )
   assign("auhtenticationKeys",auhtenticationKeys, envir=parent.frame())
  }

  authenticate()
  # Download 
  downloadData <- function() {

    # Access authentication keys:
    auhtenticationKeys$key1
    auhtenticationKeys$key2
    auhtenticationKeys$key3

    myData <- list (
      "open"  = 10,
      "high"  = 11,
      "low"   = 12,
      "close" = 13
    )

  }

  downloadData()

}


runAll()
```

By this line:

`assign("auhtenticationKeys",auhtenticationKeys, envir=parent.frame())` your keys are available inside download data and you can run your code. 
You can see more here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs